# Is there a simplistic method of getting kinect sensor to recognise swipes

Tags: kinect, gestures

I'm not the best programmer and I'm trying to adapt the skeletal tracking project available from [channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Skeletal-Tracking-Fundamentals) but I have no idea how to do so. I've also looked at kinect toolbox but it seems overly complicated. I'm trying to create an application that allows the user to make a left swipe and it uses a defined keybind such as ctrl+b when its detected.

Can anyone help or does anyone have any advice?

Kind Regards,

Aislinn

Answer (score 1):

you can create a simple algorithm.

Swipe is a move form point A to B. You just need to know when the hand is in point A. If it is there start tracking the history of moves and compare to samo pattern. For example pattern can be a horizontal move from A to B where hand shouldn`t go up or down just to the side. So check if in every frame is going straight to the side. If it goes to much up or down you cancel the move and do nothing.

Comparing to pattern is simple math. You just check position X and Y: X for move to the side and Y for the move up and down.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Haha You keep writing the exact same thing I keep thinking about! Ive gotta think faster to beat you next time:)